# Making transition transform work in i.e9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

Is there any way I can get this to work in i.e 9 , some research tells me no and another research tells me yes but not sure how ....

```
.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  -ms-transform: -ms-translateZ(25px);
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: -webkit-rotateX(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
 -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}
```

I am happy to accept that css may not accmoodate i.e 9 in this way and therefore am happy to use a js solution if people think that is the best way forward.

Comment: look into dhtml filters.